# What sets are legal in Momir Basic?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-online

What sets does MTGO randomly chooses cards from for the Momir Basic format?

I'm pretty sure things like Unglued and Unhinged are out, but what about Commander?

Also how are banned cards dealt with? An example would Stoneforge Mystic, this card is banned in Modern, but is legal in Legacy. Could I have this be a two drop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as actual legality goes, the only cards legal to have in your deck are [Momir Vig, Simic Visionary](http://magiccards.info/extra/other/vanguard-mtgo-3/momir-vig-simic-visionary.html), as well as [Plains](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPlains%5d), [Island](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIsland%5d), [Swamp](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSwamp%5d), [Mountain](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMountain%5d), and [Forest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bForest%5d).

This is hinted at on [the Wizards page](http://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/formats/momir-basic), as well as stated clearly in [this article](https://www.mtggoldfish.com/articles/introduction-to-momir-basic):

> (...) your deck contains 61 cards. One is the Momir Vig, Simic Visionary Avatar and the other 60 cards are basic lands. (...)

---

For cards to be randomly chosen, [this article](http://www.starcitygames.com/magic/multiplayer/12118_The_Momir_Basic_Primer.html) describes it as follows (original links omitted):

> (...) the random creature you get is picked from the entire Online Classic card pool. This even includes premium cards from sets that have not been released online, such as Preacher from The Dark, or Serra Avatar from Urza's Saga.

Naturally, this only applies to games on MTGO - if you play Momir Basic any other way (for example using a random generator like [MTG Familiar](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.gelakinetic.mtgfam) to determine the random creatures), no particular limits apply, and your group of players should decide which cards or editions to exclude, and whether to allow cards that are banned in certain formats.

Comment: I don't see how your first claim follows from the Wizards source you link. The link just says you need exactly 60 normal basic lands and one Momir Vig. How are you getting your claim that every single other card is banned?

Comment: Further Googling seems to indicate that you can't have anything but those 60 lands and a Momir Vig. The wording on the Wizards page sounds like you could have more, though. Is there some sort of implicit deck size limit here that I wasn't aware of?

Comment: @user2357112: While it's not spelled out explicitly, your deck may only contain those 61 cards, therefore all other cards are not legal. I wouldn't go as far and say that they're banned, since they don't appear on any official ban list, but the result is the very same. I've edited the answer to include this along with another source.

Comment: @user2357112 The way that the various format pages work on WotC's site is they list all the cards that are legal (usually by listing the sets), then listing all the banned cards. So the fact it only lists Momir Vig and basic lands means those are the only things legal in the format

Answer (score 2):

Momir Basic does not have a ban list of any kind. However, your card pool is limited to creatures that has been put on Magic Online - and since un-sets have never been printed online, those cards can't show up. Most (if not all - I'm genuinely not sure) of the Commander products have been printed online, so those cards are available.

To view a full list of creatures, in MTGO, go to your collection, uncheck "My Cards", and filter for creatures only. That'll give you the complete list of cards (and you can filter that further if you'd like to, say, look at all the possible 13 drops).